# Circuit Nodal Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, voltage-divider

I have a voltage divider feeding into an op-amp voltage follower buffer circuit. I'm trying to calculate the voltage level at the non-inverting input of the op-amp vs. the source voltage. The possible supply voltage is roughly in the range `[0V, 5V]`.

[image: Amplifier circuit]

First I tried using a simple voltage divider, so:

$$
V_A = R_2 / (R_1 + R_2) * V_S
$$

However, when I tried simulating this circuit in TINA-TI, the nodal voltages don't match those calculated.

I thought that was because the notion that there is no current flowing through the op-amp input wasn't truly non-zero, so I tried compensating for the op-amp input resistance and capacitance.

[image: No amplifier]

This time, the output voltage should be:

$$
V_A = (R_2 || R_3) / (R_1 + R_2||R_3) * V_S
$$

While this equation does match TINA-TI's simulation of the no op-amp circuit, it still doesn't match the op-amp circuit.

What else am I missing?

edit:

further information: I'm using the [LMH6612](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6611.pdf) op-amp.

Suppose I want to target an output voltage of `2.5V`. According to my first equation the required source voltage is `~2.82V`. By recursively updating my simulation I calculated that the actual required source voltage is `~3.47V`. Using the second circuit the required source voltage is closer, but only marginally at `~2.87V`.

Comment: How far off is the simulator from the analytical solution? Did you account for the op-amp offset current. At 0.01 uA, this would cause about 1 mV difference.

Comment: I updated my post with a test scenario. The difference is on the order of `~0.5V`.

Comment: Is this happening at DC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further reading into non-ideal op-amp behavior it looks like it's actually the op-amp input bias current that's the culprit.

`R1||R2 ~= 100kohm`, which created about a 0.6V drop (close enough to what the difference was). Adding a resistor to the inverting input equivalent to `R1||R2` fixed the problem.

Reference:
[Practical Considerations: Bias current](http://www.opamp-electronics.com/tutorials/practical_considerations_bias_current_3_08_15.htm)

The fixed circuit:

[image]

Comment: A schematic of where you added that resistor might be useful to other users in the future whom find your question with similar problems.

Comment: good suggestion, done.